# Is there a shorter version of a regex?

Tags: c#, .net

I have these strings
`C910 C918 C920 C924 C925 C926 C928 C929 C930 C937 C940 C942 C943 C947 C950`

and this regex works

```
^(C9[1-5]0|C9[12]8|C94[237]|C92[4569]|C937)$
```

but can it be made shorter and more elegant?

Comment: Do you *only* want it to match *exactly* that sequence?

Comment: @CodyGray yes i do thank you

Comment: well you can factor out the `C9`, which seems to be common to all strings.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann no - there might be strings which have, for instance, C8 instead of C9 as the first two characters

Comment: @PaulStevens well, that's not something anyone could know based on the sample data you provided. or the regex you provided, which wouldn't catch chose either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, bring `C9` out as its common to all terms you require.

```
 ^(C9)([1-5]0|[12]8|4[237]|2[4569]|37)$
```